# Splunk Dashboard - difference between eval case and rangemap result

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-dashboard

I'm running a query to bifurcate splunk results into buckets. I want to divide and count files based on sizes they are taking on disk. This can be achieved using `rangemap` or `eval case`.

As I read [here](https://wiki.splunk.com/Community:Search_Performance:_Use_Eval_Instead_of_Rangemap) using `eval` is faster than `rangemap`. But I'm getting different results on using both.

This is the query I'm running -

```
<source> 
| eval size_group = case(SizeInMB < 150, "0-150 MB", SizeInMB < 200 AND SizeInMB >= 150, "150-200 MB", SizeInMB < 300 AND SizeInMB >= 200, "200-300 MB", SizeInMB < 500 AND SizeInMB >= 300, "300-500 MB", SizeInMB < 1000 AND SizeInMB >= 500, "500-1000 MB", SizeInMB > 1000, ">1000 MB") 
| stats count by size_group
```

and this is the result I'm getting -

[image]

Whereas using `rangemap` this is the query -

```
<source> 
| rangemap field=SizeInMB "0-150MB"=0-150 "151-200MB"=150-200 "201-300MB"=200-300 "301-500MB"=300-500 "501-999MB"=500-1000 default="1000MB+" 
| stats count by range
```

I tried this range too - `rangemap field=SizeInMB "0-150MB"=0-150 "150-200MB"=150-200 "200-300MB"=200-300 "300-500MB"=300-500 "500-1000MB"=500-1000 default="1000MB+"` and I get the same result -

[image]

There is not a huge difference in both the images results, and we can probably live with it - but I see for the range 150-200MB - it is `445958 vs 445961`, and for 200-300 MB it is `3676 vs 3677` and for 300-500 MB it is `3346 vs 3348`. I want to understand why is that difference, and which one should I trust more? Speedwise `eval` seems better, but datawise is it not so correct?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're seeing is your `rangemap` has overlapping values.

Whereas with the `eval` format, you're trimming the ranges "properly" with `case`.

Sidebar - you can make that `case` simpler thusly:

```
| eval size_group = case(SizeInMB < 150, "0-150 MB", SizeInMB < 200, "150-200 MB", SizeInMB < 300, "200-300 MB", SizeInMB < 500, "300-500 MB", SizeInMB < 1000, "500-1000 MB", 0=0, ">1000 MB")
```

Since `case` expressions stop evaluating as soon as a match is made, no need to use `AND` as you'd had it. And using `0=0` for your last possibility will *always* evaluate true (think of `default` in `case` statements in C or C++).

Comment: yeah I tried that too, that was giving the same difference in values.